Wrong date format when reading outlook calendar event
Through API I read my outlook calendar and show it in a calendar from the FullCalendar library.
My problem occurs when reading an event with a duration, that all the events created in Outlook at the time of displaying them in my web calendar are subtracted two hours from the beginning and the end, I attach an exemplary image:
OUTLOOK EVENT


translation: Wed, 06/05/2024 from 1:30 p.m. to 3:00 p.m.

EVENT ON MY CALENDAR


translation: Start: 06/05/2024 11:30 a.m. | End 06/05/2024 13:00 p.m.

both occur on the 5th but the original event in outlook starts at 1:30 p.m. and ends at 3:00 p.m. and my calendar reads it as if it started at 11:00 a.m. and ended at 1:30 p.m., two hours apart.
In my code I put a message in the console to see how the time arrived from the reading with the API and it arrives in this format: Wed Jun 05 2024 11:30:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
so I suppose that from outlook it is arriving wrong, but I am surprised since where I live the GTM is the correct one.
This is the part that gets the events:
//EVENTS
async function getCalendarEvents(accessToken) {
    const response = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        const errorText = await response.text();
        console.error(`Error al obtener los eventos del calendario: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`, errorText);
        throw new Error('Error al obtener los eventos del calendario');
    }

    const data = await response.json();
    return data.value.map(event => ({
        title: event.subject,
        start: event.start.dateTime,
        end: event.end.dateTime,
        allDay: event.isAllDay
    }));
}

This is the part of the code that deals with the event information:
function renderCalendar(events) {
    const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    const calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        buttonText: {
            today: 'Hoy',
            month: 'Mes',
            week: 'Semana',
            day: 'Día',
            list: 'Lista'
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        locale: 'es',
        events: events,
        eventClick: function(info) {
                       
            // Get the event properties
            const event = info.event;
            const title = event.title;
            const start = event.start;
            const end = event.end;
            const allDay = event.allDay;
                        
            const timeZone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
                       
            const startFormatted = start.toLocaleString('es-ES', { timeZone: timeZone });
            const endFormatted = end ? end.toLocaleString('es-ES', { timeZone: timeZone }) : 'Evento de todo el día';
                        
            // Create the event information string
            let content = `<h2>${title}</h2>`;
            if (!allDay) {
                content += `<p><strong>Inicio:</strong> ${startFormatted}</p>`;
                content += `<p><strong>Fin:</strong> ${endFormatted}</p>`;
            } else {
                content += `<p><strong>Evento de todo el día</strong></p>`;
            }

            // Show SweetAlert2 popup with event information
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Información del Evento',
                html: content,
                icon: 'info'
            });
                
            console.log(info.event);
            console.log(title);
            console.log(start);
            console.log(end);
            console.log(allDay);
        }
    });
    calendar.render();
}

Thanks a lot!
EDIT: Although @derpirscher's solution has worked perfectly, I added another way that a colleague recommended to me that also works
async function getCalendarEvents_Alt(accessToken) {
    const response = await fetch('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
        const errorText = await response.text();
        console.error(`Error al obtener los eventos del calendario: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`, errorText);
        throw new Error('Error al obtener los eventos del calendario');
    }

    const data = await response.json();

    const events = data.value.map(event => {
        // Convertir las fechas y horas a objetos de fecha considerando la zona horaria
        const start = new Date(event.start.dateTime);
        const end = new Date(event.end.dateTime);

        // Ajustar la hora para reflejar la zona horaria local
        const timeZoneOffset = start.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; // Convertir minutos a milisegundos
        const localStart = new Date(start.getTime() - timeZoneOffset);
        const localEnd = new Date(end.getTime() - timeZoneOffset);

        return {
            title: event.subject,
            start: localStart.toISOString(), // Convertir a cadena ISO para asegurar la representación correcta de la fecha y hora
            end: localEnd.toISOString(),
            allDay: event.isAllDay
        };
    });

    return events;
}



What is the time zone on the event in outlook? The two hours off is exactly the time zone offset of CEST to UTC. So it seems, the clientside does interpret the received date as 13:30 and 15:00 in UTC, which would exactly be 11:30 and 13:00 CEST respectively. How do you read the event from the API? Can you trace that call in the network inspector and show the raw data received from the API? And where/how is that info object created?

@derpirscher The response from the network inspector is this createdDateTime :  "2024-06-12T08:41:37.1442878Z" and
end :  {dateTime: "2024-06-12T09:30:00.0000000", timeZone: "UTC"} and my code gets the date as: Wed Jun 12 2024 09:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time ) but the event in my Outlook calendar starts at 11:00, my calendar time format is (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris.

@derpirscher Sorry that I have given you the end time and not the start time, this is the start time in the network inspector section start :  {dateTime: "2024-06-12T09:00:00.0000000", timeZone: "UTC"}

If your timezone is central europe then your current UTC offset is +2:00 hours. But yeah, it seems, when converting the API response to a date object (ie that value you get from info.event.start you lose the information that "2024-06-12T09:00:00.0000000" is supposed to be an UTC timestamp. Ie your local browser treats it as it was in the local timezone, thus the 2 hours difference. How is that API response converted to that event object?

@derpirscher I have added the part of my code where I get the events in case it was useful

Well, as I said: you just take the dateTime: "..." of your result object and totaly neglect the timeZone information. So when the timestring is parsed to a Date object, it's considert to be local time ... But still there is some point missing: where do you convert the dateTime which is a string to a Date object? Because when you use it in const startFormatted = start.toLocaleString('es-ES', ...), start already is a Date object ... This is the point where you have to consider the timezone from the API response.

@derpirscher the only time I deal with the time is within eventClick: function(info) {

That seems rather unlikely, as express.json() does not convert string to Date but when you access the event.start in that handler, it is already a Date ... Maybe it's none of your code and some library is doing the conversion. But it happens somewhere ...

You are neglecting the timezone information you get from the API. Your response contains timestamps in the format
{
  dateTime: "2024-06-12T09:30:00.0000000", 
  timeZone: "UTC"
} 

but in your code, when reading the API response, you only consider
  ...
  start: event.start.dateTime,
  end: event.end.dateTime,
  ...

and ignore the event.start.timeZone information.
Thus, somewhere in your process you probably do something like
new Date(start)

to convert your timestring to a Date object. But as the timestring does not contain any information about the timezone, it's considert to be in local time (ie in your case CEST, which is 2 hours ahead UTC).
Ie "2024-06-12T09:30:00.0000000" in UTC is the same point in time as "2024-06-12T11:30:00.0000000" in CEST. But when you do new Date("2024-06-12T09:30:00.0000000") in a computer which is running in CEST, it will interpret this timestring in CEST (because it doesn't have any other information) thus, resulting in a 2 hour shift of your timestamps.
So when converting your strings to Dates you have to consider the correct timezone, these strings are referring to. A very simple approach could be the following
Check if the Outlook API always  delivers timestamps as UTC timezone. If yes, just add a Z to your timestamp strings. This is the simplest marker for dateparsing, that the timestamp is to be considered as a UTC timestamp. Ie
new Date("2024-06-12T09:30:00.0000000") will give you 9:30 CEST but new Date("2024-06-12T09:30:00.0000000Z") will give you 9:30 UTC which is the same as 11:30 CEST. Be aware, this solution breaks, if the returned timeZone is something different than UTC!
If you want to be sure, to always have the correct time if the Outlook API returns also different timezones, you have to get that information into the timestamp somehow. Looking at the docs of that API, the timeZone information is returned as Olson name (ie something like Europe/Paris or UTC), so to correctly parse that you need a library which can correctly handle this information (the built-in Date class isn't too good with that, at least when parsing). So you could for instance use moment-js (but this is considered depreacted and should not be used anymore)
import { moment } from "moment-timezone"

...
start: moment.tz(event.start.dateTime, event.start.timeZone).toISOSTring();

or a more modern library like luxon
import { DateTime } from "luxon"


...
start: DateTime.fromISO(event.start.dateTime, { zone: event.start.timeZone }).toISO();

Both of the snippets above will set start to a string containing the respective timezone information. Ie either leaving the time portion as UTC and append a UTC timezone marker, or convert the time to local time and append the respective offset information. Thus, the string can then later be correctly parsed to the correct local time.

@SalmanA It should actually work (but admittedly in quite a quirky way) because it shifts the timestamp by the amout of the UTC offset. Ie it changes something like 09:00 which is interpreted as 09:00 CEST into 11:00 CEST and the toISOString() then stringifies it as 09:00Z, which is the timestamp originally sent by the API. But of course, this is only correct (same as my naive approach above) if the API always sends UTC timestamps ... To be on the safe side, OP should consider using the returned timezone when parsing the string ...

@derpirscher no it just assumes that the input time is local time new Date(<string without tz>) so it starts wrong, then adds same offset to end date which could be on other side of DST change. The API should return something useful, ideally something like -07:00 but not IANA names (which cannot be used in JS directly).

@SalmanA  "The API should return something useful, ideally something like -07:00 but not IANA names" well, tell that to microsoft ... On the other hand, maybe it's a shortcoming of JS that it can't deal with IANA. But that's a philosophical question ...
